# Duplicate Folders in "This PC" but no names

Tags: windows-10, xbox360

I got this issue where I have duplicate 'Downloads','Music','Videos','Pictures', and 'Documents' folders. The weird thing is that the other folders don't have names but they have the same icons. They are causing some applications like Windows 10 Recorder in Xbox application to not work.

Duplicate folders:

[image]

Xbox DVR recorder issue:

[image]

I tried to find the registry folders for them but no good :/ ... does any one have any idea on how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to missing subkeys under the "FolderDescriptions" registry key, or the entire key gone missing as you've found already. See [[Fix] Cannot Rename or Move Folders in Windows 10, Due to Missing FolderDescriptions Registry Entries](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-rename-move-folders-windows-10/)

That page contains the registry export of this entire branch:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions
```

Run it (ignore error when importing, it's normal, as 3 branches can't be written to.) and restart Windows.