# How to enable OneDrive icon and remove extra (non-working) icons (Win 10)

Tags: windows-10

Clicking on the OneDrive icon does nothing and I somehow acquired the extra 5 icons below "This PC" which also do nothing. Creating a shortcut to OneDrive and placing it on the desktop works OK.

[image: screen capture]

Comment: See [Special folders appear with no icons](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-rename-move-folders-windows-10/) - You may upload your `FolderDescriptions` registry key to Pastebin.com and post the link here. Also, what';s your Windows 10 version?

Comment: [windows 10 - Duplicate Folders in "This PC" but no names - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1064764/duplicate-folders-in-this-pc-but-no-names)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, they seem to be the library folders.

Right click black space on the left column and select Show libraries. Right click Libraries and select Restore default Libraries.

Or, open Libraries via File Explorer, right click specific folder, select/un-select Show in navigation pane, or, click to Restore Defaults.

For OneDrive, please open RUN, type “%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset” and end with enter.

Then, open RUN and type “%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe” to open OneDrive to check the result.

Comment: You guys are the BEST! I downloaded "w10_folder_descriptions.zip", extracted the contents, ran it. Restored the default keys and values under the FolderDescriptions registry branch. All my extra useless icons disappeared; the OneDrive icon works properly - my Win10 world is at peace again.